# SSRS Chart Showing Incorrect Percentages

Tags: reporting-services, charts, percentage

I've got a chart in SSRS.  It shows SLA percentages by day. I've added in a goal percentage of .92.  The chart is showing this as 98%.  I don't get it.  It's a calculated field.  I've just manually entered it in.  See example of chart below.

[image]

When the report is run, this is what it looks like:

[image]

This is the dataset:

`Dt         Total   SLAPct
8/3/2017    6        0.833333333
8/4/2017    7        1
8/7/2017    4        1
8/8/2017    8        0.875
8/9/2017    4        1
8/10/2017   4        1
8/11/2017   2        1
8/14/2017   4        1`

Just for grins I changed the goal percentage from .92 to .8.  After that the goal ended up at 96%.  If anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post your expression that is calculating this?

Comment: I've just recreated your chart with no issues. I created a dataset with 6 numbers between 0.8 and 1.0 . Added a chart, dropped my values field into the values bucket, added a second series and manually set the value to 0.92, formatted the Y-Axis to `p0` and finally switched off, always show zero on the Y axis. That's all I did and it worked perfectly. I'm not really sure what could go wrong. I can only suggest you start a new report and hope that it was just some odd property somewhere that was messing things up.

Comment: Is the goal percentage maybe aligned to a second (for now invisible) axis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your goal line is showing the way it is but there's a better way to display a goal line rather than adding it as a data item.

Click the axis (vertical values on the left of your chart) and enable the properties pane in the view tab. In the properties look for StripLines.

[image: StripLines]

Next click the ellipse and add a new item. Add a new strip line and play with the settings. Here is an example with the 92% goal and "Goal" as a caption to the stripline:

[image]